# update_all not updating my database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a many-to-many relationship between my reservation db and cars db, and the following is in my reservation controller and is routed to the post.

```
def reserveConfirm

pick_time = params[:pick_y].to_s+"-"+params[:pick_m].to_s+"-"+params[:pick_d].to_s+" "+"#{params[:pick_h]}:00:00"
return_time = params[:return_y].to_s+"-"+params[:return_m].to_s+"-"+params[:return_d].to_s+" "+"#{params[:return_h]}:00:00"
#@reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
@car = Car.where(:id => params[:car_id]).update(:status => 'reserved')
@reservation = Reservation.new(status:'reserved',
                               pick_up_time: pick_time,
                               return_time: return_time,
                               user_id:current_user.id)



  if  @reservation.save
    #flash[:success] = @reservation.id
    flash[:success] = 'shit'
    redirect_to(:action => 'history',:notice => 'Check out was successfully created.',:id =>current_user.id )
  else
    flash[:success] = 'success'
    format.html { render action: "reserve" }
    format.json { render json: @reservation.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

things start to get confusing from here. In my reservation controller, every time i want params[:id], i am not getting the reservation id. I have my new reservation created and routed to get in action reserve. The [:id] seems to either be nil or a car_id, since the link i have is reservation/:id(:format), and this :id is somehow the cars id instead of my new reservation id. My reserve action does Reservation.new

```
def reserve
@reservation = Reservation.new
@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
if @car == nil
  flash[:danger] = "no car found"
else
  flash[:danger] = @car.id
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @reservation }
end
end
```

I am in the jungle and everything tangles up in the woods. 
In reserve action, I can find car by car_id which is the reservation/:id filed, which is 2 here. But in my reserveConfirm, i am getting a nil @car object, which forces me to use where that finds all car with id , although only one cause the id is unique. And worse, after i get @car, i want to update its status to reserved, but when i look into db, it is not ever changed.

My form, which passes data is here:

```
<%= form_for @reservation,:url => { :action => "reserveConfirm" } do |f| %>

<%=f.label :Date%>
<%=f.date_select :pick_up_time %>

<%= f.hidden_field :car_id, :value=> @car.id %>

<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value=> current_user.id %>

<%= f.submit "Confirm",  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', class: "btn btn-default" }%>
```

Hope someone can kindly help me with this, much appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should verify if you are getting @car correctly.

I guess you are able to use 'byebug' . Try writing 'byebug' at beginning of reserveConfirm method.

```
def reserveConfirm
    byebug
    #your code
end
```

Using byebug, you can look your rails server (in terminal) and debug your code. Try writing 'params' to check all params that you are receiving. You can write 'exit' or 'continue' using byebug. (More info: [Debugging using byebug](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3631-Debugging-using-ByeBug-Gem-in-Rails-5))

If params[:car_id] exists, your code should be like:

```
@car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
@car.status = 'reserved'
if @car.update 
    #code
else
    #code
end
```

Check that and tell me how it goes.

Comment: thank you for mentioning the nice debugger. Indeed, It shows that car_id exists but it's under [:reservation][:car_id] when the action is reserveConfirm, but it is param[:car_id] when it is in action reserve. The car id gets passed over to my controller instead of a reservation id. I am expected every new reservation will likely to have a id for example, /localhost/reservation/1..n etc, and then the car_id behind it,which becomes /reservation/1..n(reservation_id)/1..n(car_id), but right now, whenever i am creating a new reservation form, before i submit it, it is always /reservation/:car_id.

Comment: ok, i understand, are you using nested resources in your routes?